# Unmet dependencies: emacs-snapshot : Depends: emacs-snapshot-common

Tags: ubuntu

Linux Ubuntu 22.04

Emacs 27.1

```
sudo apt install inxi
```

But get error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 emacs-snapshot : Depends: emacs-snapshot-common (= 20221225:105176-48db8b68a8~ubuntu22.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: What happens if you follow the suggestion and do `apt --fix-broken install`?

Comment: This is an Ubuntu problem, not an Emacs problem - please ask on the [Ubuntu SE](https://askubuntu.com/).

Comment: @FranBurstall Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/emacs-snapshot-common_20221225%3a105176-48db8b68a8~ubuntu22.04.1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)